# Getting token_not_provided when using Authorization Header with JWT Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, jwt

I read [this tutorial](http://blog.nedex.io/create-an-api-server-for-mobile-apps-using-laravel-5-1/) and I managed to make it work perfectly. The only problem is that when I switch from **?token={token_here}** to **Authorization Bearer {token here}** it stops working.
I'm using Postman and I'm writing **Authorization** in the Header field and **Bearer{white space}{token}** in the value.
The library I'm using is https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

I read in the Wiki about the Apache problem and I'm not sure if that's my case. I diagnosed it with PHP function [**getallheaders()**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.getallheaders.php). If I *die and dump* that function, it shows that the Authorization Header is available. I tried with and without the .htaccess modification.

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

#    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.)
#    RewriteRule . - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]    
</IfModule>
```

**Route File**

```
dd(getallheaders()['Authorization']);
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function() {

    Route::post('login', 'AuthenticateController@email');

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth', 'jwt.refresh']], function() {
        Route::post('logout', 'AuthenticateController@logout');

        Route::get('test', function() {
            return response()->json(['foo' => 'bar']);
        });
    });
});
```

Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong?

**Reminder**: if I use **http://localhost/projects/linus/public/api/test?token={token}** it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was that the header configuration in the .htaccess file was missing a `*` in both lines. Instead of

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.)
RewriteRule . - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

it show be

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Special Thanks to [James-Daddies](https://github.com/james-daddies).