# Login fail in laravel 5 (JTW)

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, routes, jwt

When it comes to access my login I have this error:

```
{"error":"token_not_provided"}
```

I have in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

I have in my routes.php:

```
Route::post('/api/login', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
Route::get('/api/login', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
```

and I have my AuthenticateController:

```
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;

class AuthenticateController extends Controller
{
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        // grab credentials from the request
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        try {
            // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
            if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }

        // all good so return the token
        return response()->json(compact('token'));
    }
```

Can you help me? thank you very much greetings

Comment: Can you see the headers your browser sends, and is there something like: `Authorization:Bearer` + a long key?

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101810/getting-token-not-provided-when-using-authorization-header-with-jwt-laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure your view has: {!! csrf_field() !!} and you don't need to have it as a hidden field in the form.

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">

  @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
  <p class="alert alert-danger">{{ $error }}</p>
  @endforeach 
  
  {!! csrf_field() !!}

  <fieldset>
```

Comment: thank you very much managed to fix the bug adding to: Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth', 'jwt.refresh']], function() {
 Route::post('logout', 'Api\AuthController@logout');
 Route::get('test', function(){
  return response()->json(['foo'=>'bar']);
 }); and within this feature all the functions that make mention login. Thanks again, regards

Answer (score 1):

Where is your view? I think you need to include something on your blade.

```html
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

If you are not using a view and you are doing this from an external request. Then you can just disable the csrf_token()

Here is a link [How to disable Middlware CSRF in Laravel](http://laravel.io/forum/11-14-2014-disabling-the-csrf-middleware-in-laravel-5)