# Hi we are using Laravel Jwt Auth says error token not provided

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my Htacesss file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

Routes

Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth1']],function() {
        Route::post('/{profile_type}/balance1/{client_id}','Admin\ProfilesController@balance');
    });

kernel file 

<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
       // \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ];

/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'auth.isSuperAdmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsSuperAdminMiddleware::class,
    'auth.isAdmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsAdminMiddleware::class,
    'auth.isAuthorise' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsAuthorisedMiddleware::class,
    'auth.isCardholder' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsCardholderMiddleware::class,
    // 'jwt.auth' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken::class,

    'permissions' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckPermissionMiddleware::class,
    'isValidCard' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsValidCardMiddleware::class,
    'jwt.auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\JWTUserFromToken::class,
    'jwt.auth1' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken::class,
    'jwt.refresh' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken::class,
    'checkProfileType' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckProfileTypeMiddleware::class
];
}

GetUserFromtoken

<?php

/*
 * This file is part of jwt-auth.
 *
 * (c) Sean Tymon <tymon148@gmail.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware;

use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException;

class GetUserFromToken extends BaseMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
    {
        if (! $token = $this->auth->setRequest($request)->getToken()) {
            return $this->respond('tymon.jwt.absent', 'token_not_provided', 400);
        }

        try {
            $user = $this->auth->authenticate($token);
        } catch (TokenExpiredException $e) {
            return $this->respond('tymon.jwt.expired', 'token_expired', $e->getStatusCode(), [$e]);
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            return $this->respond('tymon.jwt.invalid', 'token_invalid', $e->getStatusCode(), [$e]);
        }

        if (! $user) {
            return $this->respond('tymon.jwt.user_not_found', 'user_not_found', 404);
        }

        $this->events->fire('tymon.jwt.valid', $user);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

please need some advice on how to proceed with this.thanks

Comment: From where you are passing the token? where is the client implementation?

Comment: From Authorization : Bearer { Token } in POSTMAN.client Implementation is ANGULAR JS.This is for API.

Comment: can you show the stack trace or error log?

Comment: {
    "error": "token_not_provided"
}

Comment: so the above error you received on man or angular app?

Comment: i got the following error while using postman

Comment: refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101810/getting-token-not-provided-when-using-authorization-header-with-jwt-laravel

Comment: I have used that it still does not work

Comment: where you have included your .htaccess file?

Comment: yes in public folder

Comment: Try to check your web server configuration. If .htaccess is enabled

Comment: Hi the problem was solved by using this $headers = apache_request_headers(); in getusertoken middleware.thanks for all the help